# Rails solution to record every single user action that can be queried later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, redis

I'm looking for a solution that does the following in general:

- Logs every single user action. If possible, in form of controller name, action, and the parameters
- Also, records what was actually changed to model objects only. For example, a controller may get long list of parameters, but only two of them are actually saved to the model object - I'd like to know what attributes were changed.
- This data can be queried - for example, looking up history of user's actions on the CRM application

We have a shared model setup for the multiple applications (all hitting the same database), so we are able to record which application the data came from. This is where we'd like to implement something like this, in a central location that is common to our applications.

The reason for doing this is because we do a lot of forensics after the fact - we get asked to check to see who changed something to a record, so we often have to go to production log and search for that information there. We'd love to be able to query for it instead using standard SQL if possible.

Another reason for doing this is because different developers own different applications, and sometimes some applications do not behave as it should. If I'm able to look up which application saved a particular value into a model object, that'd help.

There is no pattern whatsoever as to which controller name/action we would be looking at - we've added auditing logic on some models, but then we would get asked to check something out for a different model that we haven't set up auditing for.

We are willing to use something like Redis for this purpose if it makes sense. I have minimal experience working with Redis, and not sure if Redis is able to handle something like this.

Is this a realistic expectation - to be able to log every user action? I estimate roughly we have perhaps 300 to 500 user actions per hour total from various applications. Or should I stop exploring this possibility and think outside the box instead as to how I should be keeping track of user actions in general?

Comment: This type of thing is sometimes called an audit trail. You might want to google for gems with that name.

Comment: Yes Casper - we use Audited, but I think those "auditing" gems in general only records model changes, correct? It's not really easy mapping those events backwards to a particular controller name/action.

Answer (score 0):

Its realistic. People use Redis for general caching purpose so for just keeping track of user usage shouldn't be a problem.

Use the redis objects gem
https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects

For each action create a redis hash.

Each hash would consists of keys for each user (their ID will work). Each key would lead to the number of times that action has been done by that user.

You could even use the incr method for extra speed when your doing the tally.

Also if you want to be extra careful you could set it up that after X increments you could save the information back into the database into the user row. This of course would use up some resources but if its worth it to you, its worth it to you.

Edit:
I guess I should provide an example controller

```
class BlogController < OneForMyBabyController

   def show
     #Your Code Here
     #---------------
     if logged_in
       #When you create a new Redis::HashKey its first look to redis
       #if the object already exists it just gets it, other wise it
       #'creates it'*.
       blog_show_user_tracking = Redis::HashKey.new("BlogShowUserTracking")
       blog_show_user_tracking.incr(@user.id)
       #This is about how would deal with updating after a number of incr
       #This would require a separate look up from the incr above.
       #x here is the number of incr before you update the SQL DB
       if blog_show_user_tracking[@user.id] % x == 0
          #Update User To Reflect New Tracking
       end
     end
   end

end
```

edit: to show how to use it when only user are logged in.

Comment: Does this also allow me to record the controller name & action done by users? I don't just want to increment & decrement number of times a controller-action was used.

Comment: Yes, thats what you name the redis hash. So you would do ControllerActionUserTracking where I have blog_show_user_tracking = Redis::HashKey.new("BlogShowUserTracking"). As you can see Blog is the controller and Show is the action from above. The hash itself is stored at a key so you use that key to keep track of which controller and which action.

Comment: So you would just add a check for if they are logged in or not before you record it. If your using device it has a built in method for doing so, other wise you might have to create your own.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to play with this a bit and I will be sure to 'accept' your answer if it works out. Thanks a bunch!